# How to send data to the android native code from the flutter code in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to implement android widgets in android native code of flutter. I want to send the data from flutter to the android code every 30 mins to update the android widget to show the data. How do I send data to the android side from flutter side.

Answer (score 0):

use MethodChannel

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('test.flutter.native');
```

pass to Data(Flutter -> Android)

```
try {
      final int result = await platform.invokeMethod('nativeCode');
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error : ${e.toString}");
    }
```

Get Data in Android File

```
 private static final String CHANNEL = "test.flutter.native";
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

        new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
                new MethodCallHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
                        // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
                        // TODO
                    }
                });
    }
```

See the link for more information
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-java-tab